# Json Request OMDB

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to Web Development and trying to teach myself more and more. I have worked with Javascript and barley touched Jquery. I am trying to figure out how to send a JSON Request and was hoping someone could help get me started. I am trying to send request http://www.omdbapi.com/? to pull movie data. for example what i think to pull The Godfather the request is 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=the+godfather&y=&plot=short&r=json' I think it will be something like this but not sure how to actually send the request or get the response or if this will not work at all and i need to go out and learn something like Node.

```
var response =   $.ajax({
 url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?",
  context: document.body
   }).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this call (to get Godfather info):

```
$.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Godfather&y=&plot=short&r=json", function(data) {
      console.log(data);   
});
```

If you are using Chrome with developer tool, you should see the respond in console.

Hope it's help